# Android Auto build with eclipse broken

Tags: android, eclipse

I use eclipse for my android projects and it was working without a glitch. Today I installed the new platform 14 and the new ADT 15.0.0 and lo, the "auto build on save" is now broken.

Now, to generate an apk I need to manually "Ctrl+F11" which launches the emulator. I do not want to launch the emulator as I am testing on a real device. I just need the apk that is generated every time I save a file. Did something change in the new platform/adt to break this?

I have tried everything- re-installing the platforms, re-installing adt, re-installing eclipse, cleaning and building. Nothing works!

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? I have tried all the obvious things- installed the old ADT version again, checked the "Build Automatically" flag in eclipse. Still no effect.

Comment: After wasting many hours to find out what broke eclipse, I temporarily fixed my problem using new builders under Project->Properties->Builders and choosing "Ant builder" to run ant under auto build mode.

But this is a clumsy way. If anyone knows what caused eclipse to stop auto builds in the first place, please post it here; I would still love to fix that instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I am talking to myself. But I found the answer to my problem so posting it here for someone stuck like me.

The flag "Skip packaging and dexing..." under Windows->Preferences->Android->Build was somehow checked. Unchecking it did the trick.

Flags be damned!